# Open LUKS volume using key stored in kernel keyring

Tags: linux, encryption, luks

Has anyone managed to have cryptsetup open a LUKS volume using a passphrase stored in the kernel keyring? According to [this](https://fossies.org/linux/cryptsetup/docs/Keyring.txt) article (see towards the bottom) it should be possible.

I have a passphrase loaded in the keyring for root with read permissions:

```
# keyctl list @u
1 key in keyring:
 57767030: --alswrv     0     0 user: nixos_data:passphrase
# keyctl describe 57767030
 57767030: alswrvalswrv------------     0     0 user: nixos_data:passphrase
```

If I open the encrypted volume by explicitly piping in the content of this key, the volume is successfully unlocked:

```
# keyctl pipe 57767030 | cryptsetup open /safe.img nixos_data_decrypted --key-file -
```

From the linked article, I understood that to have cryptsetup read the key directly from the keyring, I should add a token to the luks device like this:

```
# cryptsetup token add --key-description nixos_data:passphrase /safe.img
```

After which I should be able to open the device without explicitly specifying the passphrase like this:

```
# cryptsetup open --token-only /safe.img nixos_data_decrypted
```

Running this with `--debug`, however, gives the following output:

```
# Activating volume nixos_data_decrypted using token -1.
# Validating keyring token json
# keyring_get_passphrase failed (error -126)
# Token 0 (luks2-keyring) open failed with -22.
# Releasing crypt device /safe.img context.
# Releasing device-mapper backend.
# Unlocking memory.
Command failed with code -1 (wrong or missing parameters).
```

Full output can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/RdN-MSF/1572e7df07eb4b94ab0c7d84835ebdaa).

Edit: Omitting the --token-only option does not change this, in that case cryptsetup asks for an existing passphrase and so still does not use the passphrase stored in the kernel keyring.

Comment: Try the open command without the `--token-only` option, it's not in the example link. Other than that, perhaps the key description is wrong

Comment: I followed your example to get it to work just fine for me - thanks! I realize it's 18 months later; maybe something was fixed? Hint: my description didn't contain a colon character, perhaps that matters?.

Comment: Have you by any chance are also using black/red keys? If so, how to format it as luks2 using CAAM?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that worked for me:

```
realpath /dev/disk/by-uuid/<your_device_or_partition_UUID_here> | xargs -I{} gio mount -d {}
```

You must have fstab and crypttab correctly configured for this to work. For example:

/etc/fstab:

```
/dev/mapper/mypartition_crypt  /media/user/mypartition/  ext4    noauto        0       0
```

/etc/crypttab:

```
mypartition_crypt UUID=<your_device_or_partition_UUID_here> none luks,noauto
```

Not sure if this works for auto mounting at boot time, but it works when invoked manually from CLI within user session